# FileUploadParser doesn't get the file name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just want to create a REST API that receives a file, process it and return some information. My problem is that I am following this example:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

And I can't make it work using Postman or curl, I think I am missing something. The parser always gives me these two errors:

- FileUpload parse error - none of upload handlers can handle the stream
- Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter.

This is the code:

views.py:

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=204)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=204)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'predict/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', app.views.FileUploadView.as_view())
]
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for GenderAPI project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = removed

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser'
    )
}


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [    

    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',   
    'rest_framework',
    'app'  


]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'GenderAPI.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'GenderAPI.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = BASE_DIR
MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'
```

Here you can see a postman capture (I have tried everything):

```
PUT /predict/pabloGrande.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:52276
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="04320cf.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

requirements:

```
bleach==1.5.0
Django==1.11.6
djangorestframework==3.7.1
html5lib==0.9999999
Markdown==2.6.9
numpy==1.13.3
olefile==0.44
pandas==0.20.3
Pillow==4.3.0
pip==9.0.1
protobuf==3.4.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
scipy==1.0.0rc1
setuptools==28.8.0
six==1.11.0
tensorflow==1.3.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.8
Werkzeug==0.12.2
wheel==0.30.0
```

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You request is a Multi part request from POSTMAN, so you should be using `MultiPartParser` instead of `FileUploadParser`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In django REST framework. we have components like Parsers, Renderers and Serializers.

- The responsibility of Parsers is to parse the data that is sent by request methods GET, POST and PUT, etc.
- Default parser used in django REST is '[JSONParser](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L38)'. It only parses the data JSON data[numbers, string, date]. It ignores the data like FILES.
- In order to parse the FILES we need to use parsers like "[MultiPartParser](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L40)" or "[FormParser](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/parsers.py#L74)".

  Example Code :

  ```
      from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser
      from rest_framework.response import Response
      from rest_framework.views import APIView

      class ExampleView(APIView):
          """
          A view that can accept POST requests with JSON content.
          """
          parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

          def post(self, request, format=None):
              # to access files
              print request.FILES
              # to access data
              print request.data
              return Response({'received data': request.data})
  ```

When we use property `request.data` then parser will parse the data.

References: [Django REST Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/), [Django REST Github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/)

Comment: With your code and this call I still don`t receive the file:

POST /predict/pabloGrande.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:52276
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="pabloGrande.jpg"
Content-Type: */*
< ./pabloGrande.jpg

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Comment: @PabloCastilla access it with `request.FILES['file']` . updated above answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 4):

I face the same problem.The problem error message shows:

> {"detail":"Missing filename. Request should include a
>   Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."}
>   I do all the steps above my answer but it doesn't work.Finally,

**I find the reason is in the backend of viewset.**

it shows like this

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser)
```

and I remove the FileUploadParser

```
  parser_classes = ( MultiPartParser, FormParser)
```

and It works, so I think you should pay more attention to it

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<insert-your-file-name>
```

to the header has solved my issue, and then in the view method where you access this file in the following manner:

```
file = self.request.FILES['file']
```

Comment: You can also access the file with `request.data.file`

Comment: @smac89, This only works assuming you use rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser and this won't work for rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser

Answer (score 2):

On the second error `Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter.` using postman I removed the header `Content-Type :multipart/form-data` and was successful.

It seems the issue is the custom Content-Type header overrides the default Content-Type header that should be sent. Check this thread for reference [Content-Type for multipart posts](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `MultipartParser` or `FormParser`.

What you need is a serializer with a `FileField()` like so:

**serializers.py:**

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # I set use_url to False so I don't need to pass file 
    # through the url itself - defaults to True if you need it
    file = serializers.FileField(use_url=False)
```

So then when you try to access `file` here below, you'll have a dict with a key named `file`. Personally, I'd probably name it something more descriptive than just "file", but that's up to you.

```
from .serializers import FileUploadSerializer

    class FileUploadView(APIView):

       def post(self, request):
           # set 'data' so that you can use 'is_vaid()' and raise exception
           # if the file fails validation
           serializer = FileUploadSerializer(data=request.data)
           serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
           # once validated, grab the file from the request itself
           file = request.FILES['file']
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py change the parser like this

`parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser)`

Comment: `JSONParser` will only applies when `Conteny-Type` header is set to `application/json`. No need to use `JSONParser`.