# API endpoint returns TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am writing a create user API by extending the class `users` with `AbstractBaseUser` class. The API was working fine for regular `model fields` like `EmailField`, `CharField`, `BooleanField`. But then I decided to store the `profile_picture` of users as well. So I create a new field `profile_picture` as `ImageField` to store the path of user's profile picture in the same extended `users` model.

**models.py**

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    """
    This model is used to store user login credential and profile information.
    It's a custome user model but used for Django's default authentication.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', max_length=None, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # defing a custome user manager class for the custome user model.
    objects = managers.UserManager()

    # using email a unique identity for the user and it will also allow user to use email while logging in.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Then I updated  `UserAPIView` class to add `parser_classes = (FileUploadParser)`

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import status
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser



class UserAPIViews(APIView):
    """
    """

    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        """
        print(request.data)
        serialized_data = serializers.UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():

            try:
                user_id = serialized_data.save()
            except IntegrityError as error:
                message = f"Email already exist."
                return Response ({
                    'error_message' : message,
                    'status' : status.HTTP_226_IM_USED
                })

            subject = 'Eitan - Case Manager Account Credentials'
            body = f"Hi {serialized_data.validated_data.get('first_name')} Your case manager account is ready. Please use following credentials to login. Email - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')}, Password - {serialized_data.validated_data.get('password')} Thank You! Team Eitan."
            sender = "steinnlabs@gmail.com"
            to = serialized_data.validated_data.get('email')

            send_mail(subject, body, sender, [to], fail_silently=False)

            success_message = f"User has been created."

            return Response({
                'success_message' : success_message,
                'status' : status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            })

        else:
            return Response (serialized_data.error_messages)
```

Updated `settings.py` to add `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`

**settings.py**

```
# Image upload configurations
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

Now, when I try to hit the end point at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/` it returns -

```
TypeError at /user/create/
'type' object is not iterable
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just had to add parser classes to parse the `request.data`.

```
parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser)
```

should be

```py
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
```

Or use list `[]` instead of tuple.

Python interprets `x = (something)` in the same way as `x = something` if you don't add a comma.

Comment: Now it returns `{
    "detail": "Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."
}`

Comment: This is a different error. The one you asked about has been solved! Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806335/fileuploadparser-doesnt-get-the-file-name/46895937

Comment: could you tell me how to pass the request to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/`. I have never created image upload API before. I don`t know how to send the JSON request to upload files. Do I have to mention the path of image file as a value to key `profile_picture` in my JSON object?

Comment: You can use a form and get the content with `request.FILES`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822823/django-jquery-ajax-file-upload