# Save Image from url Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to save an image from a url in the post request.

Here is what I have so far, the error is while passing the file to the serializer.

```
#models.py
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location_picture, max_length=255
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owned_pictures')

#views.py
class PlanPostPictureByUrl(APIView):
    '''
    Class to post dislike to plan
    '''
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        img_url = request.data["picture"]
        name = urlparse(img_url).path.split('/')[-1]
        response = requests.get(img_url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            serializer = PlanPicturesSerializer(
                data={"picture":ContentFile(response.content)})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


#serializers.py
class PlanPicturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ['picture']
```

This is the error I am getting from the serializer:

```
{'picture': [ErrorDetail(string='No filename could be determined.', code='no_name')]}
```

Comment: share the error detail

Comment: @Mirza715 just edited my post.

Comment: `        `response = requests.get(img_url)` to `response = requests.file.get(img_url)`

Comment: `img_url = request.FILES.get("picture")` do this and you will get the File.

Comment: request has neither file nor files as attribute...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806335/fileuploadparser-doesnt-get-the-file-name/46895937

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this in my serializers `create` and `update` methods.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile

url = validated_data['newIconFromURL']
# Remove url from the submitted data
validated_data['newIconFromURL'] = ''
# Download data from url (requires `requests` module.  Can also be done with urllib)
response = requests.get(validated_data['newIconFromURL'])
# Set icon field (ImageField) to binary file
validated_data['icon'] = UploadedFile(BytesIO(response.content), name='icon')
```

Note that the file name does not need to be unique, as Django will append random characters to the actual filename to make it unique.